# Get Customer from Order inside Observer function

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, event-observer

I need to make a custom customer attribute available as email template variable.

I created the following Observer, that executes just fine.

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddExtraDataToTransport implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
    $order = $transport->getOrder();

    $transport->addData([
       'test' => 'this is a test',
    ]);
  }
}
```

How would I get ahold of the order's `Customer` here?

I tried using `$order->getCustomer()` which returns null.
I expected it to return the `Customer` Object.

After reading the code of `Order` I expected this to work.

[\Magento\Sales\Model\Order Line 46:](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ce74b2/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order.php#L46)

```
* @method \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer getCustomer()
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddExtraDataToTransport implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
  ){
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
  }

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
    $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($transport->getOrder()->GetCustomerId());

    $transport->addData([
       'attr' => $customer->getCustomAttribute('attr')->getValue()
    ]);
  }
}
```

Not sure if this is the easiest way though. Comments are appreciated!